# NSSplitView - force screen update after setVertical:YES or setVertical:NO

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using an NSSplitView with a toggle button that is supposed to toggle the split between Vertical and Horizontal layouts.

As setVertical: is looking for a BOOL, toggling the orientation is quite simple:

```
    [splitView setVertical:![splitView isVertical]];
```

The part that's making me scratch my head to the bone is that it won't redraw the screen UNTIL I physically resize the app's window... ???

To hopefully redraw the screen, I've tried: `[view display];`,  `[view displayIfNeeded];`, `[splitView displayIfNeeded];` and dozens of other things to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
[splitView setVertical:![splitView isVertical]];
[splitView adjustSubviews];
```